# Istio: How can I configure NetworkFailPolicy?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, istio

I’m looking for ways to maintain high availability in the case that one of the policy pods is unavailable and found the following information on the official website:

https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/istio.mixer.v1.config.client/#NetworkFailPolicy

But I did not find any additional information on how to apply these rules in my deployment. Can someone help me with this and tell me how to change these values?

Answer (score 1):

What you´re looking for can be found [here](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/), in the istio documentation Destination Rules

Specifically check this [link](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ConnectionPoolSettings-HTTPSettings)

---

This istio [blog](https://istio.io/blog/2017/0.1-using-network-policy/) about Using Network Policy with Istio redirects us to Calico documentation.

> Network Policy is universal, highly efficient, and isolated from the pods, making it ideal for applying policy in support of network security goals. Furthermore, having policy that operates at different layers of the network stack is a really good thing as it gives each layer specific context without commingling of state and allows separation of responsibility.
>
> This post is based on the three part blog series by Spike Curtis, one of the Istio team members at Tigera. The full series can be found here: https://www.projectcalico.org/using-network-policy-in-concert-with-istio/

---

Additional links which could be useful:

- [Calico Network Policy](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.8/security/calico-network-policy)
- [Kubernetes Network Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)

Comment: Thanks for the links.

I found a way to configure the parameters I need using EnvoyFilter. But I'm not sure if that is the best solution. On the official website, I found the following information:

https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/annotations/

However, this did not work in my case.

Comment: Hello @KubePony, EnvoyFilter is very powerful so it might actually work, but i´m not familiar with it so I cant help you with that. There istio [istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/) about it. And some more informations [here](https://blog.envoyproxy.io/how-to-write-envoy-filters-like-a-ninja-part-1-d166e5abec09).